# Order of Mirror Entity and Mind Control Tech Effect Resolutions

Tags: hearthstone

Example:

Player 1 has a Mirror Entity in play (Secret: When your opponent plays a minion, summon a copy of it).  He also has 3 minions on the board.

Player 2 starts his turn with no minions and plays a Mind Control Tech (Battlecry: If your opponent has 4 or more minions, take control of one at random).

What happens?  Extra credit: what happens if Player 2 started with 3 minions before playing his Mind Control Tech?

Just trying to wrap my head around the mechanics.  Thanks.

---

Edit: this is different from the [How is effect precedence determined](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163137/how-is-effect-precedence-determined) link because the accepted answer on that question is not relevant to Secrets and does not go into detail on their usage.

In that answer, quote: "According to Lead Designer Eric Dodds, events such as Deathrattles that are triggered simultaneously will occur in the order in which the related cards were played.".

Secrets don't enter the stack when they were played, but rather *as they are triggered* which is a subtle but important point to this question (and something I learned through the accepted answer on here and some of the commentary from Waterseas).

Comment: The extra question is easy, Mirror Entity created minions don't activate their Battle Cry at all. So nothing happens anyway.

Comment: Rereading the question, I feel like it might just be due to the inability to create a short specific question title.

Comment: @Waterseas - yeah, also maybe the extra credit should've been separate.  My confusion there was because the card wording is "summon a copy of it" instead of "put a copy of it into play", so I didn't know if the battlecry occurred or not.

Comment: @spudone Nah, the extra credit is perfectly fine. Just thinking maybe the question title should be reworded to 'Order of Mirror Entity and Mind Control Tech Effect Resolutions' or something more specific. Would help people who have had this specific question before find this as well.

Comment: If a question isn't clear, *ask for clarification*.  That's not an excuse to ask another question.

Comment: It was a continuation of the same scenario presented.

Comment: I am really confused why this was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @Waterseas: I think people were quick on the draw without reading it carefully.

Comment: @Frank: I don't know who your comment was directed at but the condescending tone isn't helpful.

Comment: I'm responding to your edit.  I haven't played hearthstone, but we don't allow duplicate questions, just as everywhere on the SE network.  You're challenging a duplicate closure with, "It's not clear".  I pointed out the action we prefer, one you have enough reputation to carry out.  I wasn't attempting to be condescending in any manner.  If it came off as such, I apologize.  In any case, I haven't played Hearthstone, so I have no idea if your question is actually a duplicate or not.  Hence why I have limited my actions to attempting user education.

Comment: @Frank Thanks - I'll update the edited part to be more precise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It goes like explained this [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/168596/61395), using a stack to decide which goes first.

P2 plays `Mind Control Tech`, it goes on the stack.

P1 `Mirror Entity` triggers, it goes on the stack.

nothing else happens (no more secrets on P1 side) after so the things on the stack are "popped" out.

P1 `Mirror Entity` resolves first, and since `Mirror Entity created minions don't activate their Battle Cry` as Rai Zarek commented, even with 8 minions on P2 side, P1 won't get any.

P2 `Mind Control Tech` resolves, the minion is put into play, its battlecry effect goes on the stack and happens right away as nothing happens after the minion gets on the field, and take control of one of the 4 minions of P1.

Comment: I had viewed that other answer and thought it was specific to "start of turn" effects.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Jonathan, as much as I appreciate the linking to my answers, I feel like the first one about order of turn entry isn't actually relevant to your excellent answer. Might just want to go ahead and remove it.

Comment: @waterseas Indeed, after reading entirely the answer, it doesn't help or clarify my answer or help on the question. Thanks.

Comment: Also, "putting them on the stack based on the order the cards entered the battlefield" is a little misleading with Secrets, as they're not pushed onto the stack until they get triggered, from what I'm reading.

Comment: @Spudone that's part of why I suggested it, order of entry isn't actually relevant in regards to a secret versus something else, only in regards to multiple secrets.