# How does the Hobgoblin buff work?

Tags: hearthstone

[image]

I have some trouble understanding how this buff works. So, what I found out, it does not work when using Paladin hero ability(summons a 1/1 Silver Hand Recruit). I am not sure about other summoned creatures (like Snaketrap, Ball of Spiders,etc..). So does this buff only applies to creature-cards played from hand?

Second thing I am not sure about is the order this buff applies. So if you have 2 hobgoblins on board, is the buff applied twice or only one time (because creature has already 3 attack after first hobgoblin buff is applied). Also if you have other buffing effects/creatures on table, does the hobgoblin buff always apply or is this more a random first buff wins approach?

> All 3 Answers are acceptable. I accepted Tims , because he answered first, but upvoted all.

Comment: These 2 questions are not directly related but they offer good knowledge on how Hearthstone manage effects : [This one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/166050/61395) and [this other one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/168596/61395).

Comment: It's also worth noting that as a general rule, Hearthstone resolves effects sequentially in the order the cards were played/brought on to the board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me clear up the first part - "playing" means to have the card come from your hand. Hero powers, while some produce minions (Paladin/Shaman/etc), that is not considered "playing a minion".

If you have multiple of the same card (like the Hobgoblin) the bonuses do stack, which makes that a very formidable tactic. I do the same with the Priest class and the healing powers -- the Northshire Cleric card, it's a 1 att/3 health minion that every time a minion is healed, I draw a card. If I have 3 of them down, I get 3 cards every time I heal. I notice that good opponents tend to take those cards out first whenever possible because of those benefits.

Buffs definitely stack, although some occur one-time (ie Battlecry) and are permanent, but others are "while this minion is active". I've not had this card yet, so I'm not exactly sure which one it is, but it could definitely change the tide of the match if you have several down and are able to play other minions afterward.

Comment: The OP also asked about cards that summon creatures.  I can confirm that Master for Battle (summon 3 1/1 Silver Hand Recruits) does NOT get the hobgoblin buff, and I would expect similar cards (Snaketrap,Ball of Spiders, etc.) would not be affected either

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear in my post -- if it's not played by your hand, it's not affected.. (and summoned minions aren't played). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The priest card you are thinking of is called Northshire Cleric.

Comment: @Sorean that's the one :)

Comment: @TimS. Played minions do count as summoned minions, so _some_ summoned minions are played. Summoning can just happen from other sources than playing (hero power, additional minions summoned, spells that summon). Just elaborating that summoning and playing aren't mutually exclusive, but playing is a subset of summoning.

Comment: @TimS. In reply to your last paragraph (while this minion is active / permanent effect), the question is whether it's a triggered action or not. E.g. acolyte of pain is triggered on taking damage, whereas a dire wolf alpha continually emanates the +1 attack to adjacent minions. The former is indicated with a lightning symbol on the minion portrait, a permanent effect has no indication (except card text). Hobgoblin is in the former category as it _triggers_, it doesn't just emanate +1/+1 (because that would mean the effect disappears when the hobgoblin dies, like stormwind champion)

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Hearthstone wiki](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Hobgoblin), the Hobgoblin **only affects minions played from the hand**, but two Hobgoblin buffs **do** stack.  That means a 1/3 [Voidwalker](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Voidwalker) will become a 5/7.  The buff also applies before other enchantment effects, so if you have a [Dire Wolf Alpha](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Dire_Wolf_Alpha), the 1-attack minions that you play will still receive the buff.

Answer (score 2):

Hobgoblin's buff will only apply to minion cards--that is, cards which are themselves minions. This is what's meant by "when you **play** a minion". The buff will not affect minions summoned in any other way, including hero powers (Paladin and Shaman), spell cards (Ball of Spiders, Muster for Battle), or minions summoned by other minions (Violet Teacher).

If you have two Hobgoblins on the board, the buff will apply twice. This makes sense, because all the card asks is whether you summoned a minion with 1 attack--and you did. Even if you also trigger a Sword of Justice or there is a Raid Leader on your board, Hobgoblin should still trigger for the same reason: regardless of what the minion's attack is when Hobgoblin's effect gets to resolve, the minion card itself has 1 attack.

Source: [Hearthstone Wiki](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Hobgoblin)