# What happens if Baron Rivendare and Dreadsteed die at the same time?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone there are the two minion cards **Baron Rivendare** and **Dreadsteed**.

The Baron's ability is *"Your minions trigger their Deathrattles twice"* and the Dreadsteed has *"Deathrattle: Summon a Dreadsteed."*

Imagine the first player has both on the table. What happens if the second player **kills both at the same time**, say with a card which kills all minions?

Does the first player remain with one or two Dreadsteeds?

I read the answer to the [question suggested in the first comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163137/how-is-effect-precedence-determined), but the situation is different here. There it were two cards with *Deathrattle*. Here is just one. Anyway the answer indicates that it relies on the order the cards were played. But I am not sure at all...

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I actually don't think it is. This SHOULD be similar to how Cult Master and other cards do when they die, but it still might be different.

Comment: @Waterseas Baron is an active effect it is not a triggered effect (i.e. no lightning bolt), so how cult master works is probably not very relevant. Also the way cult master works is not obviously consistent with how similar other cards work (i.e. armorsmith).

Comment: @PVAL The comparison to Armorsmith doesn't actually make sense for how cult master works. Damage happens, then things that trigger from damage happening happen, then Death happens, then things that trigger from death happening happen. Which is why it would make sense that Baron wouldn't work in this case, but it still might.

Comment: Recommended reading for all related questions would be this rulebook: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Advanced_rulebook#Death_Phases_and_consequences_of_Death

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple answer to the question is that you get 1 Dreadstead back on the field.

Using your example, I'll use [Twisting Nether](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Twisting_Nether) as my board clear (Though any other board clear will have the same result).

Only the single deathrattle from the dreadstead will occur. Your Baron is not "alive" to trigger the deathrattle a second time.

The first set of pictures show Dreadstead played first. 
[image]
[image]

This set shows Baron Rivendare played first.
[image]
[image]

As you can see in both cases, only the single deathrattle from each Dreadstead takes effect because there is no Baron alive to trigger the second one.

Comment: As I commented on the other answer, have you tested this?

Comment: Yes with a friend. Should have taken screenshots. I might when I get home from work later.

Comment: Please do. Will incredibly strengthen your answer.

Comment: Thanks Sorean! Your answer is much more precise and not just based on experiences. I changed the accepted answer to yours. I would have tested it myself, if I had a Dreadsteed...

Answer (score 11):

For some minions, their effect does not trigger if they die.

For example, you have a Cult Master (draw a card when a friendly minion dies), and 4 different 1-health minions.

Your opponent (Paladin) plays consecration, killing **all** your minions.
**Result: You draw no cards**

If your opponent is a mage, and plays Arcane Explosion instead, all your minions *but* the Cult Master will die.
**Result: You draw 4 cards** (one for each minion)

---

Although I haven't had extensive experience with Baron Rivendare specifically, I assume this to apply similarly. Rivendare's power does not work when Rivendare dies.

---

**EDIT** Addition to the below comment thread

- **Deathrattle** triggers when the minions die. Order of deathrattles = order of said minions being played. Deathrattles that summon minions do so *after* the current action has completed.
- **Triggered** effects (lightning bolt) only trigger when the appropriate condition is met **and** the minion with this power does not die during the same action.
- **Active** effects (no lightning bolt, e.g. Stormwind Champion or Dire Wolf Alpha) are always active and only deactivate *after* the minion with said power dies.

I'm not sure about **Inspire**, as I haven't seen too many inspire plays yet.
My expectation is that the Inspire action only triggers *after* the hero power is used (and its effect has applied). So the order of operation would be:

1. Play inspire minion. ("Inspire: This minion gets +1 attack")
2. Use hero power (let's say Mage)
3. 1 damage done to target (from mage hero power)
4. Minion gets +1 attack.

This would be analogous with how e.g. Lightwarden works. Their attack gain only occurs after the rest of the action has been resolved.

Comment: This would mean, that player 1 would be left with one Dreadsteed, no matter which card was played first, as the answer to the possible duplicate question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163137/how-is-effect-precedence-determined indicates.

Comment: Yes. What order the card was played in is only relevant to work out the order of **Deathrattles**. Baron Rivendare's power is not a deathrattle in and of itself, so that does not apply in this case.

Comment: This is what I guess, too. But what rule applies then?

Comment: The rule that triggered effects (the one with a lightning bolt on the minion portrait) do not apply if that minion dies during the same action.

Comment: I read that Deathrattle effects always happen after damage has been calculated. What I don't know is, when a minion is considered as dead. Maybe after all Deathrattles have taken place. Would be reasonable since Deathrattles take place, after damage has been calculated, which means after the health dropped to 0 or below.

Comment: You current train of thought is out of scope for the Rivendare question. The power simply never triggers, regardless of when any minion is considered dead during said action. I don't see a point in considering "when a minion is considered as dead. Maybe after all Deathrattles have taken place." as it has no functional difference for the current topic.To further prove my point: The effect will also not trigger if a Paladin plays an Avenging wrath that kills the dreadsteed first. Avenging wrath is considered a **single** action, so Rivendare does not trigger even if he dies after the dreadsteed.

Comment: So an ability doesn't trigger when one action kills the minion, except the ability is a Deathrattle? Are you sure? Does a minion trigger its *Inspire* when it is killed from the owners hero ability?

Comment: Let me update my answer for minion power types.

Comment: Thanks Flater for the explanations. I would like to add *Enrage* to the list, which triggers even after the minion took lethal damage, but before it dies. Every ability (Deathrattle, Inspire, Enrage) seems to behave different in this regard.

Comment: @Flater Awesome detailed answer.  Based on your explanation of Deathrattle timing, I understand now what Thaddius is summoned twice if Stalagg and Feugen die simultaneously.

Comment: Question. Has this actually been tested by anyone answering this? If no, then I would argue its possible this is not the correct answer.

Comment: "Trigger" effects can still work when the minion dies, if you kill a Frothing Bezerker, by hitting it, it's attack will go up, then it dies. It depends on the trigger.